# Iterate Thru All Possible Combinations, Summing Another Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as below:

| user_id | sales | example_flag_1 | example_flag_2 | quartile_1 | quartile_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 21 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 300 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 41 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 55 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

...

I'm attempting to iterate through all possible combinations of (in my example) example_flag_1, example_flag_2, quartile_1, and quartile_2. Then, for each combination, what is the sum of sales for users who fit that combination profile?

For example, for all users with 1, 1, 1, 1, what is the sum of their sales?
What about 0, 1, 1, 1?
I want the computer to go through all possible combinations and tell me.

I hope that's clear, but let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Use `itertools.product()` to generate the combinations, `functools.reduce()` to generate the mask, and you're off to the races:

```
import itertools
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "sales": [10, 21, 300, 41, 55],
        "example_flag_1": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        "example_flag_2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "quartile_1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
        "quartile_2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
    }
)

flag_columns = ["example_flag_1", "example_flag_2", "quartile_1", "quartile_2"]
flag_options = [set(data[col].unique()) for col in flag_columns]
for combo_options in itertools.product(*flag_options):
    combo = {col: option for col, option in zip(flag_columns, combo_options)}
    mask = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [data[col] == option for col, option in combo.items()])
    sales_sum = data[mask].sales.sum()
    print(combo, sales_sum)
```

This prints out (e.g.)

```
{'example_flag_1': 0, 'example_flag_2': 1, 'quartile_1': 1, 'quartile_2': 1} 65
{'example_flag_1': 0, 'example_flag_2': 1, 'quartile_1': 1, 'quartile_2': 2} 0
...
{'example_flag_1': 0, 'example_flag_2': 1, 'quartile_1': 3, 'quartile_2': 1} 0
{'example_flag_1': 0, 'example_flag_2': 1, 'quartile_1': 3, 'quartile_2': 2} 0
{'example_flag_1': 0, 'example_flag_2': 1, 'quartile_1': 3, 'quartile_2': 3} 300
{'example_flag_1': 0, 'example_flag_2': 1, 'quartile_1': 3, 'quartile_2': 4} 0
...
```

Comment: This is fantastic - thanks for the help. If I wanted the output to be a dataframe with all the combinations and their sum, how would I go about that? I'm assuming I'd need to concat each dictionary output to an empty dataframe?

Comment: Just save the dicts (`{**combo, "sales_sum": sales_sum}`) to a list and call `pd.DataFrame()` on that list-of-dicts.

Comment: Sorry, would I put `list_variable = ({**combo, "sales_sum": sales_sum})` at the end of the for loop? And then outside of the for loop I call `pd.DataFrame(list_variable)`? Wouldn't the list_variable need to be global?

Or could I do:
`list_variable = []
    # Your for loop here
    # At the end of the loop:
    list_variable.append({**combo, "sales_sum": sales_sum})
pd.DataFrame(list_variable)`

Comment: The latter, where creating the dataframe is outside the loop then.